# For this morphism of integral schemes $X\to Y$, if $X$ is geometrically reduced (irreducible) then is $Y$ also geometrically reduced (irreducible)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, schemes, birational-geometry

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field. Suppose that $C/k$ is an integral curve which is birationally equivalent to a projective line. Is it true that $C$ is geometrically reduced and irreducible?

This is of course true if $C$ is a normal, since then $C$ is just isomorphic to some open subset of the projective line. So I guess the above question can be generalized to the following one:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two integral (so both reduced and irreducible)
>   schemes of finite type over $\text{Spec }k$ and
>   let $X\longrightarrow Y$ be a finite, birational $k$-morphism.
>   Suppose that $X$ is
>   geometrically reduced (irreducible). Is then $Y$ also geometrically reduced
>   (irreducible)?

Comment: When $X$ is integral, being geometrically reduced or geometrically irreducible is a property of the field extension $k(X)/k$, so the property is invariant by birational morphisms.

Comment: Good catch! I haven't looked at the problem this way. Would you mind turning your comment into answer?

Comment: From this point of view, the answer is yes when $X\to Y$ is just assumed to be dominant. If you agree with my comments, you could copy them into an answer. I stopped to write answers.